# async mvvm freezes GUI

Tags: asynchronous, mvvm, f#

My objective is to

1. start a GUI effect,
2. await some async work without freezing the GUI
3. do a final GUI effect

I've prepared a first demo code using a viewmodel with the following

```
member this.RunSetStatus() = 
    async {
            this.Status <- "!Start resetting @" + DateTime.Now.ToString "yy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss"
            let! task = async {

                do! Async.Sleep (10 * 1000) 
                return "!Reset done @" + DateTime.Now.ToString "yy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss"
            }

            this.Status <- task
        } |> Async.StartImmediate
```

It behaves as expected so I'm happy with the above.
The issue is when I replace the Sleep in the demo with real blocking work, like a wcf consumer, retrieving some results.

```
member this.CheckReport(user : string) =
    async {
        let endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof<IClaimService>),
                        new BasicHttpBinding(),
                        new EndpointAddress(address))
        let factory = new ChannelFactory<IClaimService>(endpoint)
        let channel = factory.CreateChannel()
        let resp = channel.CheckReport(user) 
        factory.Close()
        return resp
    }
```

called from my final delegate command

```
let RefreshLogic() = 
    this.RefreshIsActive <- true
    async {
        let cons = ConsumerLib.ConsumerWCF() 
        let! task, msg = async {
            try
                let! resp = cons.CheckReport(Environment.UserName.ToLower()) 
                return resp , "" 
            with 
            |exc -> return [||], (ConsumerLib.FindInner(exc).Message + ConsumerLib.FindInner(exc).StackTrace)
            }
        this.Reports <- task
        this.RefreshIsActive <- false
        this.StatusMsg <- msg
        this.ExportCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged() 
        } |> Async.StartImmediate
```

It unfortunately freezes the GUI while refreshing (why?)

Comment: Can you post it here as well?

Comment: @GoFunctional Do you have control over the WCF client contracts?  Was an asynchronous version exposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `CheckReport` function.  While it's an async block, it never actually calls any asynchronous work (ie: nothing is bound via `let!` or `do!`), so the entire block runs synchronously.

Even though the work is inside of an asynchronous workflow, when you use `StartImmediate`, the work runs synchronously up to the first actual asynchronous function call, which would be bound by `let!` or `do!`.  Since your work is completely synchronous, this propogates upwards, and ends up being synchronous, blocking the UI.

If your WCF bindings were setup to include asynchronous versions that are Task returning, the best approach here would be to use the asynchronous version of the WCF method, which would look something like:

```
let! resp = channel.CheckReportAsync(user) |> Async.AwaitTask
```

Comment: @gofunctional just using switchtothreadpool or start, not startimmediate, will probably unblock the ui... but there isn't a reason for inner method to be async